# i_CTRL-x_CTRL-s Hangs VIM

Tags: vim, spell-check

When I am trying to get a word suggestion in vim with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> VIM hangs and makes it unresponsive. I am using vim 7.3 and I have a custom spellfile: https://github.com/kaleb/vim-files/tree/master/spell

#### Question:

Is there some trick to make this not hang and allow me to use the spell menu?

For a bonus, how do I get out of the unresponsive state? <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> do not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This had something to do with terminal treating CTRL+s as XOFF, which means the terminal will continue to take input but display won't change.

Do CTRL+Q, this unhangs vim.

To disable this kind of behaviour you can put this in your .bashrc

```
stty ixany
stty ixoff -ixon
```

I believe you can type reset to load those configurations. Else logout-login. Else reboot :)

Comment: SPESHUL thanks to http://raamdev.com/2007/recovering-from-ctrls-in-putty/

Comment: I knew about ctrl-s, and didn't think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> suspends terminal transmission. If you do not want to shut this feature off in your terminal, you can issue the following vim command: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>. Make sure you are not holding down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key when you hit the <kbd>s</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to resolve terminal setting conflicts with vim, you can use `gvim` or `mvim`, the GUI interfaces to vim.  There is also `MacVim` if you're running OSX.